# Fody Costura not compiling into an exe

Tags: .net-core, console-application, fody-costura

I have a .Net Core Console Application with a number of dependencies.  My idea was to use a .Net weaver ([Costura](https://github.com/Fody/Costura)) to embed all the dependencies into the executable.  However, what seems to be happening is that it's creating a dll, and embedding all the resources into that, and then having the executable with a single dependency of the dll.  The `FodyWeavers.xml` looks like this:

```
<Weavers xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="FodyWeavers.xsd">
  <Costura />
</Weavers>
```

Is there a way to make Costura weave all the dependencies into the exe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by default a Net Core Console Application does not produce an exe. have a look at this thread https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/6237#event-1901524875

So i suspect costura is working by design, your project is building a dll and costura would be bundling references in to that dll.